# Link is moving when I hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, highlight, effect

I'm all new with this CSS coding but learning a little bit every day... now I managed to add an highlight hover effect on a link.

Now I have a little problem because the highlight rectangle is not very high and does not cover the text very well. I find it not visually appealing. I added the line "height: 18px;" but now the text is moving on hover.

Is there anything I can add to the code to keep the text stable?

This is my site:

http://tinyurl.com/gwhbzf8

I removed the "height: 18px;" from the hover CSS code so now it is normal but you will see the highlight is very thin and doesn't cover all the text. I'm talking about the side bar on left side.

Many thanks for your help!

From a CSS noob

Comment: What's your CSS code to add the highlight on hover?

Comment: .sidebar li a:hover {color:black;
background-color:#b6b6b6;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:245px;
}

.sidebar li a:link{
  display: block;
}

Comment: I also made it so the effect work on the whole sidebar + clickable area too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is caused by the line-height of the link in:

```
.sidebar ul {
    ...
    line-height: 80% !important;
}
```

Play around with this or add padding to the link to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you André

Comment: I added some padding on top and bottom (3px), and did minus 3px on the margin to keep the same distance between each lines!

Comment: .sidebar li a:link{
  display: block;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom:3px;
padding-left:5px;  
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: -3px;
margin-left: -5px;
}

Comment: Very nice! If you got rid of the .widget li {padding: .25em 0 ... you would not need to set the negative margin on the <a>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your line-height of 80%:

.sidebar ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0px; line-height: 80% !important; }